# Pure CSS Mobile Menu That Uses Neither Scripting Nor Pseudo CSS Features Nor Checkbox

Tags: css, mobile, menu

Is there a published CSS mobile menu technique that uses neither scripting (e.g., javascript, jQuery, etc.) nor pseudo CSS features nor an HTML checkbox input?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly, and why the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This does use the `:hover` pseudo *class*, but it's not a pseudo *element*. As long as the menu is a sibling of the trigger's and the `:hover` is on their common parent, and as long as the toggling menu butts up against the trigger so there's no gap in the hover state, this should work. On non-touch it'd be a hover action (or you could hide it entirely. On touch, the hover should be treated like a touch action.

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>Menu</span>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you Scrimothy, but your sollution does use a pseudo CSS feature.

Comment: @Ambassador Not sure why the need to refrain from basic <CSS3 patterns, but these are all parts of "mobile menus". It sounds like you are just looking for a traditional nav bar (either header or sidebar). You can either set it to fixed or let it scroll as normal.